# SQL Server : cast money and 2,3 or 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query that displays the number and maximum number of decimal places from a given column. It can by two, three or four decimal places.

I would like cast this number as money, but that the number of decimal places would not be cut off to two.

```
select
    reverse(concat(replicate('0', case when @maxSpaces > 2 then @maxSpaces else 2 end - licznik), val)) value,
    replace(replace(convert(varchar, cast(reverse(concat(replicate('0', @maxSpaces - licznik), val)) as money), 1), ',', ' '), '.', ',') as value_money
from 
    @TABval
```

[image]

I want to get exactly this format:

[image]

Comment: If 2012+, take a peek at format().  That said, formatting should REALLY be performed in the presentation layer.   For example try  
Select Format(19998.018,'# ##0.000')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, it's not that simple. Note the comma as the decimal point.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Format allows for a culture, but I can't think of one which is space and comma.   Perhaps a little imagination and a simple replace is required.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I was looking at documentation but managed to miss culture

Comment: Value_money  can be as nvarchar not money format but in this format. For example 1 876,321  or 23,00  or 1 333,3206  . The number of decimal places depends on @maxSpaces

Comment: Please clarify in the question what format the input data is, I assume the output is text since you want the number formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two variants to get the desired output using the culture parameter

```
German

SELECT FORMAT(19998.018,'# ##0.000', 'de-de')

Swedish

SELECT FORMAT(19998.018,'# ##0.000', 'sv-se')
```